# How can I print all values of for loop variable?

Tags: c++, for-loop

I wrote a program to print the hexadecimal values, octal values and the corresponding character, separated by hyphens, for the ASCII values between 40 and 126 (both inclusive). My code is:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
      int i;
      char c;
        for(i=40;i<=126;i++)
        {
            c=i;
            cout<<i<<"-"<<hex<<i<<"-"<<oct<<i<<"-"<<c<<"\n";
      }
      return 0;
}
```

it works fine but here some values of `i` are skiped. i.e 58,59 are not printed. I want to print for all values in 40 to 126 range. Have any suggestions?

Comment: http://ideone.com/NxxmVp

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to print first as decimal, you should add `std::dec` stream manipulator:

```
cout << dec << i << "-" << hex << i << "-" << oct << i << "-" << c << "\n";
//      ^^^
```

Because after first loop's iteration, flag `std::ios_base::oct` oct` still remains.

Answer (score 6):

The last manipulator you used for each call to `cout` is `oct`, and the stream "remembers" that - so, when you output `i` the next time without manipulator, it still uses `oct` as output format. Simply use `dec` explicitly for the first output of `i`:

```
cout << dec << i << "-" << hex << i << "-" << oct << i << "-" << c <<"\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the good ol' C library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=40;i<=126;i++)
        printf("%d 0x%X  '%c' \n", i, i, i);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why would you do that in C++?